# How to efficiently rack up billiards for an 8-ball game?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic

Since racking of billiard balls for the 8-ball game can be done under multiple rules, here's the racking I refer to:

[image]

i.e. the 8-ball must be in the center, and along the sides the stripes and the solids must alternate. The two remaining balls (a stripe and a solid) don't matter.

Assume you just finished a game, gather the balls, put them in the rack and proceed to arrange them to start a new one. They're now in a random order. How do you proceed?

<sub>Disclaimer: paint art follows</sub>

[image]

A simple approach would be to start in order, top -> bottom and left -> right.

So for example, we'd assume `1` is at the correct position. `5` is not, we swap it with `2`, then we swap `4` with `3` (or with `8`), but this would already be inefficient because we've either moved the `4` to the center or the `8` in `4`'s position - i.e. not where it has to be at the end.

There's also the decision of which types of balls we want in the corners to be made. How do you decide that upfront? Should you take into account how many balls are already in place? In my example, if you want the grey ones in the corners, you already have 3 in place (balls 1,10,14). If you want the white ones in the corners, you have just 2 of them in place (2,11). Should this matter?

To formalize this, we can assume there are <del>two</del> three operations we can do:

- swap two adjacent balls
- swap two non-adjacent balls
- rotate rack

Since we can use both hands, let's assume we can parallelise the first operation (swap 2 couple of balls at the same time), whereas we can only swap two non-adjacent balls at a time.

What approach is best suited for this task that minimizes the time (in the time units described)? Would greedy be best for this? (it's how I do it when I rack them up, I guess)

EDIT: As per existing (or previous answers) - you might assume having more stripes than solids in the corners means that strides will prefer corners - not saying it isn't true, but if you make that assumption, please prove it.

Comment: I'm interested in the one-handed implementation of the first operation, moreover when performed with both hands in parallel.

Comment: @JanDvorak quite easy with a bit of practice :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use an out-of-place sort?

Comment: Reminds me a bit of solving a 15 puzzle

Comment: When designing our algorithm, should we make an assumption about how many memory reads and comparisons we can make in the time it'd take to make one swap? Or is it assumed to be arbitrarily fast for both?

Comment: Close votes? It's a question about algorithms, since when are those not welcomed?

Comment: @Patashu I'd abstract those out. I'm thinking you can just read the input once and that'd be that.

Comment: The only thing that seems like it would change the cost is determining "which" outside balls are originally in the correct spot and then not moving those. Everything else has to fall into place by the rules trivially after.

Comment: @pst I thought about that, but how would you prove that is the most efficient way? Intuitively, I'd actually say it wasn't...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore do you require a time-optimal solution?

Comment: @JanDvorak "What approach is best suited for this task that minimizes the time?" - with those assumptions - you can swap two pairs of adjacent balls at the same time, only one pair of non-adjacent balls.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I mean, do you accept a heuristic?

Comment: @JanDvorak if it's optimal. There can be optimal heuristics, no?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore some problems can be solved optimally, some cannot. If you are going to calculate the solution in your head, you are particularly restricted on the amount of non-visual memory.

Comment: @JanDvorak the "in my head" would be just a bonus, in real life I wouldn't really mind a couple of extra moves. So yes, for the real-life situation, a heuristic is all I can hope for, I guess. But an optimal algorithm would also be cool to see, for educational purposes. :)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Can you solve the example in the question in less than 4?

Comment: @JanDvorak that'd be awesome. 3 swaps or 3 time measures?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Apology - three swaps can't be done in your example.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore your example can be done in three ticks: (5-2/11-12)(4-8)(3-8)

Comment: @JanDvorak it can be done in 2 actually - (2-5/3-8)(12-11/4-3)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore the balls along the perimeter can be separated to three groups - the black ball, the ones that prefer striped corners, then ones that prefer solid corners.

Comment: Can the rack be rotated without penalty? If so then the 8-ball could go in any 3 of the central spots.

Comment: @DPenner good point - I suppose it can, but it'll cost you 1 time unit :)

Comment: I thought that the black ball could end up in any of the three center positions? Does it have to end up in the top center position (#4)?

Comment: It is easy to prove that four swaps are always sufficient.

Comment: @JanDvorak yup (but you can rotate). As for proving, sure, but is it optimal? Can it be done in 3?

Answer (score 5):

NOTE! This answer was written before the rotation requirement. Proceed at your own caution :)

Here's my initial look at the problem.

The first thing to do is calculate the parity of the exterior - +1 if it would fit 'stripes in corners', -1 if it would fit 'solids in corners', +0 if it's the 8 ball. This gives us a range from +12 to -12, and we aim for the extreme we are closer to. (If +0, pick +12 or randomly)

For example, this is +1 +1 +1 -1 -1 +1 -1 -1 -1 +1 +0 -1 and thus it's -1 leaning solids in corners:

```
x o x x o
 x o x o
  8 x o
   o x
    o
```

The next thing to do is move the 8 ball into the center. *If you can do two adjacent swaps with it that moves two balls into position, rather than a single adjacent swap that moves just one ball into position (or a single non-adjacent if it's in a corner), do so.*

```
x o x x o
 x 8 x o
  o x o
   o x
    o
```

After we move the 8 ball, all combinations of two adjacent swaps sharing a ball can be produced by a non adjacent swap identically, so we have to consider far less complexity at once.

Order all remaining moves by this priority:

-A swap between two adjacent balls on the outside is 'worth 4' (2 if it's our last)

-A swap between two adjacent balls, one on the outside, is 'worth 2' (1 if it's our last)

-A swap between two balls on the outside is 'worth 2'

-A swap between two balls, one on the outside, is 'worth 1'

And perform them from top to bottom.

So we move the o on the top, left (4), the o on the right side in (2), the o on the bottom left in (2) and then swap the x top with the o in the middle (2). We ended up doing five swaps in a 2-2-1 series, so three moves.

```
o x o x o
 x 8 x x
  o o o
   x x
    o
```

(Notably, this one would have been solved just as fast if we aimed for stripes in corners.)

```
x x o o x
 o 8 o x
  o x o
   x o
    x
```

I think it's impossible to require 4 turns, but I haven't proven it to myself yet.

Another worked example:

This has a parity of +1 so we aim for stripes in corners:

```
8 o o o x
 o o o x
  o x x
   x x
    x
```

swap 8 ball with center x
(1-)

```
x o o o x
 o o o x
  o 8 x
   x x
    x
```

swap two adjacent on outer, 4 points
(1-1)

```
x o o o x
 o o o x
  x 8 x
   o x
    x
```

swap adjacent edge into center, 2 points
(1-2-)

```
x o o o x
 o o x o
  x 8 x
   o x
    x
```

swap edge to edge, 2 points
(1-2-1-)

```
x o x o x
 o o x o
  x 8 x
   o o
    x
```

3 moves.

EDIT: This works quite well for the example in the opening post, solving it in two moves:

This has a parity of +1 so we aim for stripes in corners:

```
x x o o x
 o o x o
  o o 8
   x x
    x
```

Swap 8 with x on edge then with o in center (solving two edges)
(2-)

```
x x o o x
 o o x o
  o 8 x
   x o
    x
```

swap adjacent o and x on top and bottom left (solving four edges)
(2-2-)

```
x o x o x
 o o x o
  x 8 x
   o o
    x
```

2 moves.

Comment: 4 swaps, 2 time measures - (2-5/3-8)(12-11/4-3)

Comment: Blenders I solved in 3 moves with a halfie left over: http://pastebin.com/MfRRGshn

Comment: @Patashu: But isn't that still four moves? Or are you counting two simultaneous swaps as one move?

Comment: The original post says I can do two adjacent swaps or one adjacent swap per move. This makes adjacent swaps more valuable to do, so I do as many as I can first.

Comment: Can you prove this parity approach is optimal?

Comment: I would love to, but I'm not sure how to (barring writing a program to solve it both ways and see by exhaustion if it is or isn't)

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 eight balls, cheater.

In the given example, the solution takes 2 moves:

2-5, 3-8
3-4, 11-12

An optimal solution is best found by configuring the problem for [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) (DP). Since the problem is multi-stage with fixed costs and no uncertainties, a DP matrix will exist that optimally solves the problem.

To create the matrix: note that accounting for symmetries the 8-ball can be in one of 9 positions. The solids can be arranged in about (14 choose 7)/2=1716 different ways. That means the total number of rack configurations is about 1716 * 9 = 15,444. Thus, you have 15,444 different possible states. Calculate the cost to go from any one of these states to any other. This results in a matrix with 15,444 * 15,444 cells, or about a quarter of a billion cells. Identify all the end-state cells. To solve the matrix you breadth search forwards from the starting state until you reach an end state (or until you reach a cost total greater than your current minimum cost). By doing this you will have provably found all the least cost paths.

Note that the above solution is somewhat naive and can be optimized in various ways to yield a smaller matrix. For example, you can use rotational symmetry to reduce the number of cells and add a cost of 1 (for rotating the rack) to paths that are correct except for having the 8-ball in one of the low-center positions.

```
Pseudocode:

Create DP Matrix:

(1) determine number of possible arrangements, A, of balls
(2) for each arrangement, make a list of possible unique moves  
---- the possible moves are:  
------- rotating right  
------- rotating left  
------- exchanging any pair of balls  
------- exchanging any two pairs of adjacent balls  
(3) for each move in A store a pointer to the resulting arrangement  
(4) for each arrangment make an attribute indicating whether it is an end state  

Solve Problem  
(5) goto arrangement for starting position S  
(6) set best-cost-so-far (BCSF) variable to infinity
(6) breadth search from S, accumulating current cost CC as +1 for each transition
(7) if you reach an end state CC < BCSF, then set BCSF = CC and make solution list contain only the current path
(8) if you reach an end state CC = BCSF, then add path to solution list
(9) if CC > BCSF abandon branch and try next branch

The result will be a list of all possible solutions and the minimum cost BCSF.
```

Comment: This "backtracking" doesn't really sound like DP to me. I don't have 2 8 balls though, I have 14 balls (labeled 1-14) plus an 8 ball.

Comment: In DP you can backtrack or search forward. When you have many possible end states you generally search forward from the start state, not backtrack from the end states. You are misunderstanding the way the combinations are being calculated. To determine the possible arrangements, you start with 8-ball position count (A), then you calculate the possible solid arrangements (= 14 choose 7) (B). After doing this there is only 1 stripe arrangement, so the total combinations is A * B * 1. If you use symmetries it is more complicated, but the approximate total is as I have said.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: you really have two 8 balls! one black and one white (in the center).7stripes+7whole+1black=15 but the black one *HAS* a number (eight)

Comment: I think the numbers in that image have only reference character. The black eight is _the eight ball_, the others are just enumerated _non-eight balls_. A bit confusing, admittedly.

Answer (score 4):

There are `15!/(7!7!1!)=51480` possible positions. Of these, 4 are final: balls 8 and 9 can be exchanged, and stripes/solids can be reversed. We'll say these positions are at distance 0.

For each of these 4 positions, generate all possible moves (1 swap or 2 adjacent swaps). For each position generated by these moves that has not been seen before, remember which move was used to generate it, and give these positions distance 1. Then do the same thing for every position at distance 1 and give the new positions distance 2. Keep doing this until there are no more new positions.

This makes use of the fact that, as @DPenner pointed out, rotations can always be replaced with an adjacent move.

Since swaps are their own inverse, the move to go from position A to B is also the move that will take position B back to A.

So, you end up with a list of all positions, and for each position that is not a final position a move that will with certainty bring it closer to a final position.

You will find that there are 232 positions that take at least 4 moves. (EDIT: My adjacency table contained an error earlier.) For example:

```
      6-9,14-15     2-12       2-5,4-7       1-2
    x           x           x           x           o
   x x         x x         8 x         o x         x x
  x o x   =>  x o o   =>  x o o   =>  o 8 o   =>  o 8 o
 o o o x     o o x x     o o x x     x o x x     x o x x
o 8 o o x   o 8 o x o   o x o x o   o x o x o   o x o x o
```

There are no initial positions that take more than 4 moves.

EDIT: The strategy of swapping in the 8-ball first is not optimal. For example:

```
         5-11     12-13,14-15    4-7,6-10
    x            x            x            x
   o o          o o          o o          o o
  o x o   =>   o 8 o   =>   o 8 o   =>   x 8 x
 x o x x      x o x x      x o x x      o o x o
8 x o x o    x x o x o    x o x o x    x o x o x
```

but we can do better:

```
         3-11       1-2,3-5
    x            x            o
   o o          o 8          x x
  o x o   =>   o x o   =>   o 8 o
 x o x x      x o x x      x o x x
8 x o x o    o x o x o    o x o x o
```

The problem is that x is the wrong kind for the corner, so we lose a move.

Rather, the strategy should be to look for a ball that is out of place, but that cannot be exchanged with an adjacent ball, either because they are the same kind or they are already in position. Corners should be preferred, because they have the fewest adjacent swap options. It should be swapped with a ball of the correct kind for the position. If the ball at the first ball's final position is of the wrong kind, an adjacent ball in the wrong place should be chosen. That way, a subsequent adjacent swap will put those balls in the correct final place.

In the above (counter)example, the 8 ball requires a long swap to get to its final position. However, the x in #5 is the wrong kind, so instead we swap with an adjacent o, the 2nd one in the 2nd row.

The earlier example with 4 moves is solved as follows:

```
        11-2         12-5        13-3       9-10
    x           x           x           x           x
   x x         o x         o x         o o         o o
  x o x   =>  x o x   =>  x 8 x   =>  x 8 x   =>  x 8 x
 o o o x     o o o x     o o o x     o o o x     o o x o
o 8 o o x   x 8 o o x   x o o o x   x o x o x   x o x o x
```

In the first step, we pick the o in the bottom left corner. The first x is at position two. Then we pick the 8 at #12, which we can bring home to #5. The o in the middle of the bottom row is next. We exchange it with the next wrongly placed x at #3. Finally, we swap #9 and #10 to get the final rack. The path is different from before, but we still made it in 4 moves.

EDIT: One more point: when performing adjacent swaps, preference should be given to those that do not end up with both balls in their final position. The reason is that this means that at least two moves are required in all, and so it's best to make the first move as soon as possible.

For example, the rack in the question can be solved in two moves: (2-4),(5,6) and (3-6),(12-13). The 8 ball was moved to its final position first, even though the white ball it was swapped with is not yet in its final position. If the two perimeter swaps (2-4),(12-13) were done first, you still need two moves to get to the final rack, taking a sub-optimal 3 moves total.

Comment: Nice, I had thought that 4 moves weren't necessary - and that algorithm looks sound.

Comment: Can you dump here a link to your table of the best moves for all 50k positions + its encoding?

Comment: 'The strategy of swapping in the 8-ball first is not optimal.' I think you misunderstand - the strategy of 8-ball first is not to make the center complete (one of each of the three kinds), but to go towards the filled edge that is closer. In the example you use, the board is vastly predisposed towards being completed solids in corners, so I would make a move that helps this. Swap it with the solid in the center, then do two adjacent swaps at the top corner to finish.

Comment: @Patashu It seems to me that would still leave you with one extra move: a rotation to get the 8 ball in the top of the center. My heuristic would not chose the solid ball in the center because it is already in a final position.

Comment: Since when was 'get the 8 ball in the top of the center.' a requirement? The original post says the 8 ball must be in the center, not where. If I am wrong, then you are correct though.

Comment: @Patashu Well, if the 8 ball could be anywhere in the center, then why have rotation as an option at all? It's essentially a no-op then. See also DPenner's question about rotation and OP's answer in the comments to the question (#17 or so).

Comment: Ok, my answer is outdated then :)

Answer (score 3):

This has been a challenging, deeply frustrating, and fun question all at once. My conjecture is that the following is an optimal solution:

- Choose whether stripes or solids are in the corners based on Patashu's parity method
- No rotations
- Every time-measure, make the move which scores the highest except where a +3 move can put the 8-ball in the centre
- In case of tie, choice does not matter? **Edit:** See note at bottom. Ties are difficult.

(I'm scoring moves according to the net difference in the amount of balls in correct positions.)

Here are two example racks:

```
    x            8
   x x          o o
  o o x        o o x
 o o x x      o x x x
8 o o o x    o x x o x
```

If we number the positions 1 to 15 going left to right, then top to bottom, the first rack 
solves as (2-4/3-5)(5-11)(10-13) and the second rack solves as (4-8/11-12)(5-10)(1-5).

My latest attempt at a proof had a portion of it fail on just 11 different racks up to symmetry (with the two shown above being a variation of ones that failed). Here are two lemmas I found in my attempts which will hopefully help others with proofs.

### Lemma 1: Rotations aren't necessary

Note that if we need to do a rotation at some point in our solution, it doesn't matter when (rotating doesn't change any available swaps). Further more we only need at most one rotation since 2 clockwise rotations = 1 counter-clockwise rotation and vice-versa.

So lets choose to make the rotation on our last move if needed. At this point, due to rotational symmetry of the outside, the outside must be correct. So the 8-ball would be in one of the three central balls. If its in the right spot, we don't need rotation. Otherwise, we could use it but notice that a swap would also complete the rack. It is therefore unnecessary in an optimal solution.

### Lemma 2: Greedy is optimal if it solves the rack in under 3 moves

Let strategy `A` be the greedy solution and strategy `B` be any non-greedy solution attempting to be faster. `B` must make at least one non-greedy move. By necessity this cannot be the last move. Therefore if `A` takes n turns to complete a rack, `B` must make its non-greedy move at turn n-2 or earlier. This means that if `A` solves the rack in 2 turns or less, it is optimal.

---

**Edit:** Well, I just ran my algorithm on a programmatic test, and found out its not even consistent. In fact it seems that ties are very hard to break. Consider the following rack:

```
    x
   o o
  x o x
 x 8 o x
x o o x o
```

My algorithm would do one of the following move sequences: (5-8/13-14)(7-8/10-15), (5-8/10-15)(7-8/13-14), (5-8/14-15)(10-13)(7-8), (5-8/14-15)(7-8)(10-13), (5-8/9-10)(14-15)(7-13), (5-8/9-10)(7-13)(14-15), (5-8/9-10)(13-14)(7-15), or (5-8/9-10)(7-15)(13-14). The first two solves it in the optimal 2 time-measures, but the others solve it in 3 time-measures. The problem is that the (14-15) and the (9-10) switch ruin a possible +4 move on the second turn. A modification to this algorithm would probably require a look-ahead, which then gets complicated quickly. I'm starting to think there is no "simple" solution, and the solution by @JeffreySax is the way to go. Also note that this rack also defeats the greedy solution. The greedy solution would do either (13-14/10-15)(5-8)(7-8) or (13-14/10-15)(7-8)(5-8).

Comment: Conjencture: more than three moves are never neccessary. If you prove this, we're done. I had a proof for "more than four" but it assumed black at any center position.

Answer (score 3):

Salut, first I must say this was a very fun and interesting problem, and something that I haven't thought of when racking, although at 15 total balls some extra moves wouldn't be important.

From the racking description and image we get the following **rules**:

1. corners are always the same type
2. middle of each side is always same type as corner
3. each set of 2 balls touching the corners are the always same type (and opposite type as corner)
4. inside triangle has always the 8ball, a stripe and a solid (and 8ball is on top)
5. on the sides, balls near each other will always alternate type

As @DPenner stated in `Lemma 1`, rotations aren't necessary because they can be substituted by a swap, provided the cost is the same. If you're a Rubick fan and choose to use them you would need only one.

### Can't be solved in less than 4 swaps! ( *always* )

Your example image is best to prove this, either way you count it you'll need to dislodge 6 *color* balls from their positions and the 8ball => that's 3½ swaps and because a swap needs 2 balls let's round that to 4 swaps.
Why is this?
Because it doesn't meet all the rules:

- `[5,1,4]` `[2,6]` `[11,13]` `[10,12]` cant be near each other (breaks 5)
- `8ball` is on a side and not in the middle triangle (breaks 4)
- `[5,4]` `[6,12]` `[13,9]` are not all the same type (breaks 3), moreover in the case of `[1,5,4]` the set is not opposite to the corner (breaks 3 again)
- `[2]` and `[11]` are not the same type as corners (breaks 2)

### Algorithm

[image: 8ball spots]
**1st step: fix the 8ball**
Swap the 8ball into it's position. It will need to be there anyway.
*Here's the only chance to rotate (in case the 8ball starts in the inside triangle, but incorrect position)*

**`Count` the most balls of same type in the red positions**.
Highest count balls stay, rest of the spots have to be swapped out.

```
IF count is 3 {
    #inside triangle will choose 
    IF inside triangle has 2 of a kind, that type stays (in the red spots)
    ELSE pick random
}
```

**Start swapping:**

- do the corners (pick a ball that needs changing and find an opposite one in a corner)
- do the middles (pick a ball that needs changing and find an opposite one in a middle of a side)
- *if corners and middles are done, the last swap is in the inside triangle*

### Demo on your example:

```
swap 8 with 3  #move1
count[stripe]=3 [6,13,9]  
count[solid]=3 [5,4,12]
highest count=3, checking inside, inside is correct, random pick: stripes stay
Pick 5, corners() correct, swap with middles(2)  #move2
Pick 4, corners() correct, swap with middles(11)  #move3
Pick 12, corners() correct, swap with middles(3)  #move4
Done.
```

if random pick would choose solids to stay:

```
Pick 6, swap with corners(10)  #move2
Pick 13, swap with corners(1)  #move3
Pick 9, swap with corners(14)  #move4
Done.
```

### Demo2:

*changed 3 with 7, replaced 'white ball no.8' with ball no.15*
[image: demo2_with_ball_15]

```
swap 8 with 3  #move1
count[stripe]=3 [6,13,9]  
count[solid]=3 [5,4,12]
highest count=3, checking inside, inside has 2 of a kind(stripes) => stripes stay
Pick 5, corners() correct, swap with middles(2)  #move2
Pick 4, corners() correct, swap with middles(11)  #move3
Pick 12, corners() correct, swap with middles(15)  #move4
Done.
```

*`Have fun!`*

PS: You might also like **Algorithm variation #2** that `counts` the gray positions, but I found it easier for a real-life scenario to use the red spots.

Comment: Moving the 8-ball in first is not always optimal - Take a look at the first example rack in my answer. Moving the 8-ball first results in needing 4 moves, whereas optimal is 3.

Comment: @DPenner note that less moves don't necessarily mean more efficeint. 4 moves that can be don in parallel are more efficient that 3 that can't.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Sorry, a little word confusion - I was counting a "move" as including parallel swaps...It does seem to me though that moving the 8-ball in first in that rack results in at best 4 time-measures, whereas optimal is 3 time-measures. Let me know if I'm missing something though.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about parallel ops at all, just a generic algo that is easy enough to remember and fast. I guess my alg could be improved in this sense by a way to prioritize corners()/middles() to look for adjacent balls, but this search would imply a waste of 'processing power' that should also have something to do with time...